# Javascript function to execute only once

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have been working on a script to show an alert box only once (using cookies). Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function cookie(){
    var x = document.cookie;

    if (x = "") {
      alert("Welcome to Steampunk Inc!");
      document.cookie = 'iwashere=iwashere; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 23:59:59 GMT;';
    } else if (x = "iwashere=iwashere") {
      console.log("You came back!");
    }
  }
  cookie();
</script>
```

I have this as the first thing in the body of my html file. The code is on the index page on my website [here](http://steampunk.mooo.com).

Comment: `=` is not the same as `==`.

Comment: and what is the issue? What is not working? Please edit the question to explain what is your issue.

Comment: Use methods for reading/setting cookies https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Look at the answer that I just accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using = operator with if. = operator assigns value to the variable. Instead you should use == operator to compare.

In addition document.cookie will return all cookies you have stored for your site. You should use some functions to get / set the specific cookies

Here is sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }
  function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
  }
  function cookie(){
    var x = getCookie("iwashere");

    if (x == "" || x == null) {
      alert("Welcome to Steampunk Inc!");
      setCookie("iwashere", "iwashere", 365);
    } else if (x == "iwashere") {
      console.log("You came back!");
    }
  }
  cookie();
</script>
```

Comment: I don't use a cookie finder because that is my only cookie.